# Find number in column, insert row below column, populate with data, and then repeat until it has found all of the pre-defined numbers

Tags: excel, vba

I need to find the value "5005" (only this value) in column J:J, insert a new row below it, and then fill the row with values in columns A-U.

I am new to VBA and I am unable to do this without making a mess of code.

The draft would look something like this

Find all cells with value 5005 in column J:J, 
Insert Row below, 
Put value1 in A, 
Put Value2 in B, 
etc.... until column U,
Repeat on the next cell that has "5005" in it until there are no more

I am unsure what code would work best at this point and I think seeing this written out by a pro would help significantly.

In the messy code I've provided below I was able to search for the value "5005" and insert a line below it, but whatever cell I have selected in excel will be filled with the value "TRUE" and the code is quite messy. Not sure If I was going the right direction with it.

```
Sub AAAAAAAtest()
    Dim find5005 As Range

    'Have excel search 1 column instead of all cell
    Set find5005 = Cells.Find(What:="5005", LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                              LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
                              SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=True, SearchFormat:=False)

    If find5005 Then ActiveCell.Value = find5005.Offset(1).EntireRow.Insert
End Sub
```

Comment: Where do you take the values (A-U) from i.e. what are you copying to the newly inserted row?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Narrative is in the code comments

```
Option Explicit

Sub insert5005()

    Dim rng As Range, urng As Range, faddr As String
    Dim vals As Variant

    'get some dummy values quickly
    vals = buildAU()

    With Worksheets("sheet5")

        'find first 5005
        Set rng = .Range("J:J").Find(What:="5005", after:=.Cells(.Rows.Count, "J"), _
                                     LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlPart, _
                                     SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext)

        'continue if found
        If Not rng Is Nothing Then

            'record first found cell
            faddr = rng.Address

            'start loop for insert, populate and additional cells
            Do
                'insert new row
                rng.Offset(1, 0).EntireRow.Insert
                'populate row
                .Cells(rng.Offset(1, 0).Row, "A").Resize(1, UBound(vals) + 1) = vals
                'look for another
                Set rng = .Range("J:J").FindNext(after:=rng)

            'keep going until first address is reached a second time
            Loop Until rng.Address = faddr

        End If

    End With

End Sub

Function buildAU()

    'construct some dummy values

    Dim i As Long, tmp As String

    For i = 65 To 85
        tmp = tmp & Format(i, "|v\alu\e00")
    Next i

    buildAU = Split(Mid(tmp, 2), Chr(124))

End Function
```

Comment: This is great, I am such a noob and I appreciate all the help I can get! One thing I wasn't too clear on, I have specifica values that I would like to fill in each cell in the newly inserted row. What code would be the best to have these rows filled with per-determend values?

Ex: in the new row in colum A I would like a string value like "rack" and in the next column I would like the value "400" 

these aren't what Im going to be filling these with, but they give you an idea,

Comment: Create an array of the 21 values like I did above.

Comment: I FIGURED IT OUT TYYYYY <3